# Amazon echo can connect via bluetooth as router with third party wearable device like a Fitbit?

Tags: bluetooth, amazon-echo

I'm making wearable device like a Fitbit.
I want to know if I can use Echo to connect our device via bluetooth as router.

Then, it should be allowed to send some data to our web server from Echo.
(For now, it's connected with smartphone)

Is this possible for third party company?

Or it will be possible in a future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can accomplish that is using alexa to call a lamba function that talks to your device:

**1) Alexa -> Lambda -> IoT (MQTT) -> your device via wifi**

**2) Alexa -> Lambad -> IoT (MQTT) -> gateway -> your device via BT**

"gateway" would be something like a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks so much. Our device supports only bluetooth connection, so should we make another product like "gateway" to accomplish that? That's so sad.

Comment: That's because echo does not support bluetooth connection to third party gadget?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

The Echo supports only a few BT devices, such connecting to your phone to stream audio through the Echo.  Maybe a few more things.

As far as I know, the only way to get the Echo to talk directly to your device via BT, is to get Amazon to buy into the idea of supporting BT connectivity to your proprietary device and very unlikely to happen.

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped for us.